# Swift - Timeout a recursive function that performs network call?

Tags: swift, networking, timeout, alamofire

I have a function that performs a network call and validates the response, and does another network call again if the response doesn't match certain criteria.  (A word from WordsAPI that doesn't have value for "results")

It keeps calling until it gets a valid result.

How do I set it so that after a certain amount of time, it stops calling and escapes with an error.  Let's say I want 10 seconds to be the limit for calls, and the network call is taking 3s each time, the fourth call should complete but the 5th call should escape with an error.

I thought about setting up a Timer to run with the first function call, and the function can refer to whether the timer is still active before continuing, but I wonder if this is a resource heavy/thread blocking way to do it.

This is what my network call looks like.

```
func fetchRandomWord(completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> ()) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: randomWordUrlString)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue(API_KEY, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-RapidAPI-Key")
    request.timeoutInterval = 10

    Alamofire.request(request).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
        guard response.result.isSuccess, let value = response.result.value else { completion(nil, response.error); return }

        let json = JSON(value)

        if let word = json["word"].string {
            //Check word has results associated
            self.fetchData(for: word, completion: { (json, error) in
                if let json = json {
                    if json["results"].array != nil {
                        completion(word, nil)
                    } else {
                        completion(nil, FetchError.MissingResults)
                    }
                } else {
                    completion(nil, FetchError.MissingResults)
                }
            })
        } else {
            completion(nil, FetchError.MissingResults)
        }
    }
        .resume()
}
```

And this function is what calls it, and keeps calling it if an error returns ->

```
    func fetchRandomWord() {
    currentWord.accept("")
    isFetchingRandomWord.accept(true)

    manager.fetchRandomWord { (word, error) in
        if let word = word {
            self.currentWord.accept(word)
            self.isFetchingRandomWord.accept(false)
        } else {
            //handle error fetching word
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            self.fetchRandomWord()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can init `Date` and check if 10 seconds have passed with `timeIntervalSinceNow` before doing another network call.

Comment: That seems really easy and obvious!  Thank you.